# iOS: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to receive any data within the timeout: 5000

Tags: java, ios, selenium, automation, appium

Unable to launch iOS application when trying to inspect element using appium desktop server. can anyone help in this? Thanks

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwBC2.png)
Configuration:

Appium : 1.22.0/1.22.2/1.22.0/1.22.0-beta

Mac OS: macOS Monterey v12.1

Xcode: 13.0

java-client - 8.0.0-beta

Selenium - 4.1.0

```
[debug] [BaseDriver] W3C capabilities and MJSONWP desired capabilities were provided
[debug] [BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {
[debug] [BaseDriver] “alwaysMatch”: {
[debug] [BaseDriver] “platformName”: “iOS”,
[debug] [BaseDriver] “appium:platformVersion”: “15.0”,
[debug] [BaseDriver] “appium:bundleId”: “xxx”,
[debug] [BaseDriver] “appium:udid”: “xxx”,
[debug] [BaseDriver] “appium:deviceName”: “iPad (7th generation)”,
[debug] [BaseDriver] “appium:automationName”: “XCUITest”,
[debug] [BaseDriver] “appium:includeSafariInWebviews”: true,
[debug] [BaseDriver] “appium:newCommandTimeout”: 3600,
[debug] [BaseDriver] “appium:connectHardwareKeyboard”: true
[debug] [BaseDriver] },
[debug] [BaseDriver] “firstMatch”: [
[debug] [BaseDriver] {}
[debug] [BaseDriver] ]
[debug] [BaseDriver] }
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: d5ff9889-3107-484f-a7ae-69040842c596
[debug] [XCUITest] Current user: ‘ravikumar’
[debug] [XCUITest] Available devices: xxx
[debug] [XCUITest] Creating iDevice object with udid ‘xxxx’
[XCUITest] Determining device to run tests on: udid: ‘xxx’, real device: true
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘xcodeDetailsRetrieved’ logged at 1646047918428 (17:01:58 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘appConfigured’ logged at 1646047918429 (17:01:58 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘resetStarted’ logged at 1646047918429 (17:01:58 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[debug] [XCUITest] Reset: running ios real device reset flow
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘resetComplete’ logged at 1646047918430 (17:01:58 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[WebDriverAgent] Using WDA path: ‘/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent’
[WebDriverAgent] Using WDA agent: ‘/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj’
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/sessions
[HTTP] {}
[debug] [GENERIC] Calling AppiumDriver.getSessions() with args: []
[debug] [GENERIC] Responding to client with driver.getSessions() result: []
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/sessions 304 3 ms - -
[HTTP]
[XCUITest] Continuing without capturing device logs: Failed to receive any data within the timeout: 5000
[XCUITest] Setting up real device
[debug] [WebDriverAgent] Parsed BUILD_DIR configuration value: ‘/Users/ravikumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-ciegwgvxzxdrqthilmrmczmqvrgu/Build/Products’
[debug] [WebDriverAgent] Got derived data root: ‘/Users/ravikumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-ciegwgvxzxdrqthilmrmczmqvrgu’
[XCUITest] {}
[DevCon Factory] Releasing connections for 8bb860208088b844840e8d0fc8c70a80fc46d631 device on any port number
[DevCon Factory] No cached connections have been found
[debug] [XCUITest] Not clearing log files. Use clearSystemFiles capability to turn on.
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘newSessionStarted’ logged at 1646047928671 (17:02:08 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Failed to receive any data within the timeout: 5000
[debug] [W3C] at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-device/lib/plist-service/index.js:67:16)
[debug] [W3C] at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
[debug] [W3C] at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 10746 ms - 599
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For me, passing bundleId via capabilities cause the same problem, so tried just connecting the device and launch the app using activateApp(String bundleId) method. This works fine for me Appium 1.22.3 and ipad 16.5

```
DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("platformName", "ios");
    cap.setCapability("appium:deviceName", "iPad");
    cap.setCapability("appium:platformVersion", "16.5");
    cap.setCapability("udid", "");
    cap.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
    IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
    driver.activateApp("org.khanacademy.Khan-Academy");
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you've followed the getting started steps in the README
Make sure your system is set up appropriately (i.e., XCode is updated, Android SDK is installed and ANDROID_HOME is set.
Make sure the paths to your applications are correct
On windows run appium.app as administrator or when running from source you need to run cmd as administrator.
When installing on Mac, make sure the user has write permissions for /usr/local/lib or install Appium with the command npm install -g appium --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root

Comment: i have all updated Xcode, Appium desktop server and appium related to iOS automation
Also ran this command npm install -g appium --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
it didn't help
updated with logs